# Android application serial number and how to store it?

Tags: android, paypal, license-key

**Scenario:**

I intend to make a donate version of my ad supported application, via paypal library. The process should be simple but effective: if the user makes the transaction, and the result is Ok, I will generate a serial number for the application and activate it.

**Questions**

- the serial number needs to be generated based on something unique on the device. What should this be, the IMEI number ? Or maybe I should consider the current google account logged on the phone? In this way if the user changes the phone, he can still use the application.
- I need to store this serial number in my application. What would be the easiest way to do this ? I wouldn't like to make a sqlite database only for this purpose, as I don't need it for something else. On each activity start I will check if the serial number is correct.

Any response is gladly taken. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use android unique id. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id).
2. The storing is really simple. Just use [shared preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I thought a little more on the issue and I thing I'll go with the current gmail account as a source for the serial number. In this way, the use can still activate the app if he gets a new device.